# How to make a column (if not first column) of a DataGrid into Hyperlink

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I'm struck, it sounds simple but i'm confused. I have a DataGrid control which populates the data at runtime from SQL Server. All i need is to make the ID column into a hyperlink (I've also tried to change the color to blue with no success)

```
 private void fillDataGrid(string strSQL)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = KaskoConnectionString.ConnectionString;
            con.Open();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DGHolder.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            //DGHolder.Columns[0].

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.ShowMessageAsync("Error", ex.Message, MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative);
        }
```

and the XAML is very basic as below

```
  <DataGrid Name="DGHolder" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="4"  Background="LightGray" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" Grid.Column="0"  FontWeight="Bold"  MouseLeftButtonUp="DGHolder_MouseLeftButtonUp">

            </DataGrid>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

Code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new[]
            {
                new Example {Company = "Google", Url = "http://www.google.com"},
                new Example {Company = "Amazon", Url = "http://www.amazon.com"}
            };
        }

        private void HyperlinkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var link = (Hyperlink) e.OriginalSource;
            Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }

    internal class Example
    {
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApp1:Example}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Company}" Header="Company" />
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Url}" Header="Url">
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="HyperlinkClick" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You need the hyperlink handler here because it's hosted in a `Window`, if it's hosted in a `NavigationWindow` then [it's automatic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridhyperlinkcolumn?view=netframework-4.7#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
<DataGrid Name="DGHolder" ... AutoGeneratingColumn="dg_AutoGeneratingColumn">
```

---

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "ID")
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn()
        {
            ContentBinding = new Binding(e.PropertyName),
        };
    }
}
```